# TestNG Based Selenium Tests not running in Parallel

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am using the below TestNG Config to enable parallel execution of Selenium tests.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Test-Automation" parallel="methods" thread-count="2" verbose="1">

    <test name="Suite Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="SampleTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="firstTest"/>
                    <include name="secondTest"/>
                    <include name="thirdTest"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Java Code:**

```
@Test(dataProvider = "TestData")
public void firstTest(String data){
   //Code
}

@Test(dataProvider = "TestData")
public void secondTest(String data){
   //Code
}

@Test(dataProvider = "TestData")
public void thirdTest(String data){
   //Code
}
```

The Selenium tests are expected to run in parallel. I expect 2 browsers to be open and run the test script.

But I see only 1 browser and all 3 tests run one after the other and not in parallel. I have tried using test, methods, class, instance options for "parallel" attribute.

Any help?

Comment: What version of TestNG are you working with ?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan : I am using 6.13.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to a bug in TestNG 6.13.1 [ See [GITHUB-1636](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1636) for more details ]

I have fixed this in the latest SNAPSHOT of TestNG (6.14-SNAPSHOT) and this should be available for use in the released version of TestNG (6.14).

But until then, please alter your suite xml file to look like below :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Test-Automation" parallel="methods" thread-count="2" verbose="1">
    <test name="Suite Test" parallel="methods" thread-count="2" verbose="1">
        <classes>
            <class name="SampleTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="firstTest"/>
                    <include name="secondTest"/>
                    <include name="thirdTest"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The work-around is basically to add the attributes `parallel="methods" thread-count="2"` at the `<test>` level also.

Comment: I am seeing this problem again in 6.14.3                                                   https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1898

Comment: @sjethvani - Then you should file a new bug, and include all supporting information along with samples etc., which can be used to recreate the problem.

Comment: I have already commented this thing under relevant issue (https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1898) . Should I file a new issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Seperate all the test and then try with parallel="test"

```
    <test name="Suite Test1">
        <classes>
              <class name="//..//packg name..SampleTest">

            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
  <test name="Suite Test2">
        <classes>
            <class name="//..//SampleTest">

            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
  <test name="Suite Test3">
        <classes>
            <class name="//..//packg name..SampleTest">

            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: Is separating all methods from 1 class to multiple test, the only way? All test methods are from single class.

Comment: This is incorrect. Separating a class with 3 methods that are part of a single `<test>` tag into 3 `<test>` tags with each class and one method is the same. This doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: ACtually this duplication works and runs in 2 browsers parallel. But this will make duplicated lines in xml config.

Answer (score 0):

No, writing just parallel = "tests" & thread-count ="2" in your testng.xml file won't cut it. That is because Selenium WebDriver is not thread-safe by default. In a non-multithreaded environment, we keep our WebDriver reference static to make it thread-safe. But the problem occurs when we try to achieve parallel execution of our tests within the framework. Every thread you create to parallelize your tests tries to overwrite the WebDriver reference since there could be only one instance of static WebDriver reference.

To overcome this problem, we can take help from the ThreadLocal class of Java. Wondering what is ThreadLocal? Simply put, it enables you to create a generic/ThreadLocal type of object which can only be read and written (via its get and set method) by the same thread, so if two threads are trying to read and write a ThreadLocal object concurrently, one thread would not see the modification of the ThreadLocal object done by the other thread, thus, making the thread-local object thread-safe.

A typical thread-local object is made private static and its class provides initialValue, get, set, and remove methods. The following example shows how you can create a Generic type thread-local object

Refer this website:
[https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/selenium-parallel-testing-using-java-threadlocal-testng-shargo#:~:text=Simply%20put%2C%20it%20enables%20you,ThreadLocal%20object%20done%20by%20the](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/selenium-parallel-testing-using-java-threadlocal-testng-shargo#:%7E:text=Simply%20put%2C%20it%20enables%20you,ThreadLocal%20object%20done%20by%20the)